# Star Wars Travel to Other Galaxies

Tags: star-wars

Hyperspace travel speeds seem pretty vague and inconsistent in the Star Wars universe, but I have seen a number of videos and websites estimating somewhere around 25,000 light years per day (depending on the ship, of course). Assuming the Star Wars galaxy is roughly the size of the Milky Way, it would take around 4 days to travel from one end to the other, effectively making interplanetary travel a non-issue that is rarely brought up.

At these speeds, it would only take 3-4 months to travel the 2.5 million light years to the Andromeda galaxy, and a number of other nearby galaxies could be reached in less than a year. This is not ideal for sightseeing or business trips, but it would be perfectly reasonable for exploratory or scientific operations. I imagine making ships large enough and comfortable enough for such excursions would not be unfeasible either.

Is there a reason why this is never done? (or is it?) Fuel costs? Risk? Simply no practical need?

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but I think for story telling reasons, since Lucas took a long time to make the first 6 films in the Skywalker Saga, there was no reason to travel to many other places outside their galaxy + Unknown Regions, even though the books/comics sometimes do. But unknown regions is also extremely hard to navigate through. The Chiss use Force Sensitive Chiss children to get from UR to the main SW Galaxy...

Comment: In Expanded Universe there was invasion from another galaxy. BTW it may already be answered on Sci-fi & Fantasy SE.

Comment: While I agree with @Mithoron this question is probably better suited for Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE sister site, the Q is clearly asking for either or in-universe (albeit expanded universe) and/or out of universe explanations and not opinions.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192981/in-star-wars-did-anyone-travel-outside-the-galaxy https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68433/is-the-star-wars-universe-just-one-galaxy